# How to capitalize letters m to z in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 uppercase = ['m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
 y=input('please write a word: ')
 for i in y:
     if i in uppercase :
        y = y.upper()
 print(y)
```

I know that the program is incorrect but I've been into python only 2 days so i'm really sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to print some characters in upper case. You can check every single character and use `print()` with `end=""` so it does not append a `'\n'`:

```
uppercase = set("mnopqrstuvwxyz")
y =input('please write a word: ')
for i in y:
    if i in uppercase:
        print(i.upper(), end="")
    else:
        print(i,end="")
print("")
```

Output (Input: qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm):

```
QWeRTZUiOPaSdfghjklYXcVbNM
```

---

You get the same if you use `''.join()` on a list comp that uppercases the needed letters:

```
uppercase = set("mnopqrstuvwxyz")
y = input('please write a word: ')
y = ''.join(i.upper() if i in uppercase else i for i in y)
print(y)
```